# Cant understand this Express JS source snippet

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I was trying to understand Express JS source and this is the main module where express is exported

```
module.exports = createApplication;


function createApplication() {
  var app = function(req, res, next) {
    app.handle(req, res, next);
  };

  mixin(app, EventEmitter.prototype, false);
  mixin(app, proto, false);

  // expose the prototype that will get set on requests
  app.request = Object.create(req, {
    app: { configurable: true, enumerable: true, writable: true, value: app }
  })

  // expose the prototype that will get set on responses
  app.response = Object.create(res, {
    app: { configurable: true, enumerable: true, writable: true, value: app }
  })

  app.init();
  return app;
}
```

I am confused about this piece of code

```
  var app = function(req, res, next) {
    app.handle(req, res, next);
  };
```

The variable `app` is assigned and used inside the function at the same time. How can this work? There is no definition of an `app` anywhere else. Find the real source [here](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/48aba21ea4bcf0dec962514553f6e6326f942dc6/lib/express.js#L38).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function is created and assigned to the `app` variable.  That's a normal function expression assignment.

Then, the two `mixin()` lines add methods to the `app` function.  So, after calling those functions, it has things like `app.handle()` and `app.init()`.

Then, two more properties `app.request` and `app.response` are added.

Then, `app.init()` is called.

Then, sometime later the `app` function is called (when an http request arrives) and when it is called, it calls `app.handle()` which is just calling a function that is a property of itself.  That's all legit.  It would be similar to calling `this.handle()` in a more traditional object.

Here's a little demo of the part that seems to have you most confused:

```js
var test = function() {
    test.doSomething();
}

test.doSomething = function() {
    console.log("doSomething");
}

test();    // causes test.doSomething() to get called
```

Comment: Oh yes. It makes sense now. Thanks!